# Plotly AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_layout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to add a title to my plot, but I get the error message:

> "AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_layout'"

The plot works without the `update_layout` line. I googled the error message without any luck.

Is there any other way to do this?

```
from _plotly_future_ import v4_subplots
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.plotly as py

fig1 = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"type": "pie"}, {"type": "pie"}],
           [{"type": "table"}, {"type": "table"}]],
)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Pie(
        labels=pie_alarms_total['alarm_type'],
        values=pie_alarms_total['alarm_timestamp'],
        name="Total Alarms",
        title="test"
    ),
    row=1, col=1

)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Pie(
        labels=pie_alarms_notbd['alarm_type'],
        values=pie_alarms_notbd['alarm_timestamp'],
        name="No TBDs"
    ),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=pie_alarms_total['alarm_type'],
            line_color='darkslategray',
            fill_color='lightskyblue'
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=pie_alarms_total['alarm_timestamp'],
            line_color='darkslategray',
            fill_color='lightcyan'
        )
    ),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig1.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=pie_alarms_notbd['alarm_type'],
            line_color='darkslategray',
            fill_color='lightskyblue'
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=pie_alarms_notbd['alarm_timestamp'],
            line_color='darkslategray',
            fill_color='lightcyan'
        )
    ),
    row=2, col=2
)

fig1.update_layout(title_text="Test")

plot(fig1, filename="test.html")
```

I want the main title for all the images on top.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found this issue in a [Juan Klopper video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yoB7oyMIlE). This is the wrong method call:

```
fig1.update_layout()
```

The correct way to update the figure layout is to call:

```
fig1.layout.update()
```

Comment: This worked, oddly I found the incorrect form from the plotly documentation: https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/

Answer (score -1):

you can just upgrade your plotly version to latest version, eg:

> pip install plotly==4.1.1